# What is the meaning of "crash" from the output of the last command?

Tags: linux, rhel, last

What is the meaning of "crash" from the output of the `last` command?

```
root     pts/0        mastrt03 Wed Jan 24 11:54 - crash  (07:12)
```

We have couple of lines with "crash" on our mastrt03 machine.

Comment: That the system crashed before you logged out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`last` command shows crash as logout time when there is no logout time specified in `wtmp` database for a user session in linux os

Normally In last command will show user login time and log out time and Time Duration of logged in

If Logout  for particular user not found in wtmp database. then it will mentioned as crash

Comment: If no user were logged in when the computer rebooted, does it mean that a crash due to hardware failure will be reported as `reboot` instead of `crash` ?